# Different Cloud Formation parameter values for every environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation

I did create a sns topic. However I wanna deploy it in multiple environments staging and prod. Like the code below for each environment.

MySNSTopic:

```html
MySNSTopic:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        TopicName: mytopic
        Subscription:
          - Protocol: 
            Endpoint: 
          - Protocal:  
            Endpoint: 

Parameters:
  Mappings:
    snsProtocol:
      qa: Email
      stg: Email
      prd: https
    snsEndpoint:
      qa: Email
        stg: Email
        prd: https
```

Parameters:
Mappings:
snsProtocol:
qa: Email
stg: Email
prd: https
snsEndpoint:
qa: Email
stg: Email
prd: https

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot, but properly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Fn::FindInMap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html):

```
Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Default: qa
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - qa
      - stg
      - prd
  Mappings:
    SettingsMap:
      qa:
        Protocol: Email
        Endpoint: Email
      stg:
        Protocol: Email
        Endpoint: Email 
      prd:
        Protocol: https
        Endpoint: https
```

and then:

```
Subscription:
  Protocol: !FindInMap
    - SettingsMap
    - !Ref EnvType
    - Protocol
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide Conditions in CloudFormation template. That will get used while creating resource. Something like below.

```
Parameters:
    EnvType:
      Description: Environment type.
      Default: test
      Type: String
      AllowedValues:
        - prod
        - test
      ConstraintDescription: must specify prod or test.
Conditions:
  CreateProdResources: !Equals 
    - !Ref EnvType
    - prod
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html#conditions-section-structure-examples